# Seeking a formal definition of a complex hyperbolic space

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I'm trying to find a formal definition of a complex hyperbolic space
that is $CH^n$.

Can anyone help me please? I tried looking online already but no formal direct definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definition of complex hyperbolic geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785999/definition-of-complex-hyperbolic-geometry)

Comment: no it does not but thank you

Comment: Perhaps, if you followed the links in the answer found there, you would also find the formal direct definition that you seek.

Comment: I did already, I didn't find a direct definition

Comment: I'm familiar with the definition in terms of the unitary group, but I want a more explicit definition if possible

Comment: it is also known to be the dual of the projective complex space $CP^n$

Comment: Then you should probably explain what you mean by a "direct definition", and what it is about those definitions that violate your concept of a "direct definition". Without that, your question is pretty vague.

Comment: Here is a definition (or a characterization): it is a simply connected complete Kaehler manifold with constant negative holomorphic sectional curvature.